# How to make the jsp page not to show the previous value set in session?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Below is my jsp file, once I process some value and display the value in jsp page. The value comes from servlet, but next time when I just enter the url the values are displayed which were there previously, so please suggest how to go about doing this?

The jsp code is :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%
       Map<String, String> reportMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        if (session.getAttribute("leaveMap") != null) {
            reportMap = (Map<String,String>) session.getAttribute("leaveMap");
        }
        String classname="",employeeid="",employeename="";
        int style =0,sno=1;
%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Comparing access-card Data with leave manager Data</title>
<link href="css/sling.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script language="JavaScript" src='script/cal.js'></script>
<!-- Below imports for Blanket purpose-->
<script src='script/blanket.js'></script>

<script>
    var _validFileExtensions = [".xls"];

    function Validate(oForm) {
        var arrInputs = oForm.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var filename = document.getElementById("myFile");
        if(filename.value.length ==0){
            alert("Please select the file to upload");
            return false;
        }else{
            for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
                var oInput = arrInputs[i];
                if (oInput.type == "file") {
                    var sFileName = oInput.value;
                    if (sFileName.length > 0) {
                        var blnValid = false;
                        for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
                            var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
                            if (sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
                                blnValid = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (!blnValid) {
                            alert("Sorry, " + sFileName + " is invalid, allowed extensions are: " + _validFileExtensions.join(", "));

                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }


        function isValidDate(element){
            var elementValue = element.value;
            var daysInMonth = DaysArray(12);
            var pos1=elementValue.indexOf(dtCh)
            var pos2=elementValue.indexOf(dtCh,pos1+1)
            var strDay=elementValue.substring(0,pos1)
            var strMonth=elementValue.substring(pos1+1,pos2)
            var strYear=elementValue.substring(pos2+1)
            strYr=strYear
            if (strDay.charAt(0)=="0" && strDay.length>1)
                strDay=strDay.substring(1)
            if (strMonth.charAt(0)=="0" && strMonth.length>1)
                strMonth=strMonth.substring(1)
            for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                if (strYr.charAt(0)=="0" && strYr.length>1) strYr=strYr.substring(1)
            }
            month=parseInt(strMonth)
            day=parseInt(strDay)
            year=parseInt(strYr)
            if(elementValue!="") {
                if (pos1==-1 || pos2==-1){
                    return errorMessage("The date format should be : dd/mm/yyyy", element);
                }
                if (strMonth.length<1 || month<1 || month>12){
                    return errorMessage("Please enter a valid month", element);
                }
                if (strDay.length<1 || day<1 || day>31 || (month==2 && day>daysInFebruary(year)) || day > daysInMonth[month]){
                    return errorMessage("Please enter a valid day", element);
                }
                if (strYear.length != 4 || year==0 || year<minYear || year>maxYear){
                    return errorMessage("Please enter a valid 4 digit year between "+minYear+" and "+maxYear, element);
                }
                if (elementValue.indexOf(dtCh,pos2+1)!=-1 || isInteger(stripCharsInBag(elementValue, dtCh))==false){
                    return errorMessage("Please enter a valid date", element);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        function formatDate(textBoxObj) {
            var elementValue = textBoxObj.value;
            for (i=0; i<elementValue.length; i++){
                if(((i==2)||(i==5))){}
                else {
                    var c = elementValue.charAt(i);
                    if (((c < "0") || (c > "9"))){
                        alert("Only Numbers Are Allowed");
                        textBoxObj.value='';
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if((elementValue.length==2)||(elementValue.length==5)){
                textBoxObj.value=elementValue+'/';
            }
            return true;
        }
        function isValidDate(element){
            var elementValue = element.value;
            var daysInMonth = DaysArray(12);
            var pos1=elementValue.indexOf(dtCh)
            var pos2=elementValue.indexOf(dtCh,pos1+1)
            var strDay=elementValue.substring(0,pos1)
            var strMonth=elementValue.substring(pos1+1,pos2)
            var strYear=elementValue.substring(pos2+1)
            strYr=strYear
            if (strDay.charAt(0)=="0" && strDay.length>1)
                strDay=strDay.substring(1)
            if (strMonth.charAt(0)=="0" && strMonth.length>1)
                strMonth=strMonth.substring(1)
            for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                if (strYr.charAt(0)=="0" && strYr.length>1) strYr=strYr.substring(1)
            }
            month=parseInt(strMonth)
            day=parseInt(strDay)
            year=parseInt(strYr)
            if(elementValue!="") {
                if (pos1==-1 || pos2==-1){
                    return errorMessage("The date format should be : dd/mm/yyyy", element);
                }
                if (strMonth.length<1 || month<1 || month>12){
                    return errorMessage("Please enter a valid month", element);
                }
                if (strDay.length<1 || day<1 || day>31 || (month==2 && day>daysInFebruary(year)) || day > daysInMonth[month]){
                    return errorMessage("Please enter a valid day", element);
                }
                if (strYear.length != 4 || year==0 || year<minYear || year>maxYear){
                    return errorMessage("Please enter a valid 4 digit year between "+minYear+" and "+maxYear, element);
                }
                if (elementValue.indexOf(dtCh,pos2+1)!=-1 || isInteger(stripCharsInBag(elementValue, dtCh))==false){
                    return errorMessage("Please enter a valid date", element);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        function DaysArray(n) {
            for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                this[i] = 31
                if (i==4 || i==6 || i==9 || i==11) {this[i] = 30}
                if (i==2) {this[i] = 29}
            }
            return this
        }
        <!-- Begin Script for progressbar
        var progressEnd = 15; // set to number of progress <span>'s.
        var progressColor = 'blue'; // set to progress bar color
        var progressInterval = 1000; // set to time between updates (milli-seconds)

        var progressAt = progressEnd;
        var progressTimer;

        function progress_clear() {
            for (var i = 1; i <= progressEnd; i++) document.getElementById('progress'+i).style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
            progressAt = 0;
        }

        function progress_update() {
            document.getElementById("statusmessage").style.display ="";
            progressAt++;
            if (progressAt > progressEnd) progress_clear();
            else document.getElementById('progress'+progressAt).style.backgroundColor = progressColor;
            progressTimer = setTimeout('progress_update()',progressInterval);
        }

        function progress_stop() {
             document.getElementById("statusmessage").style.display ="none";
             clearTimeout(progressTimer);
             progress_clear();
        }
        // End for progressbar-->

         function submitform(){
                var oForm = document.getElementById('accesscarddata');

                var startdate = document.getElementById("startdate").value;
                var enddate = document.getElementById("enddate").value;
                if(startdate == ""){
                    alert("Please select Start Date.");
                    return false;
                }
                if(enddate == ""){
                    alert("Please select End Date.");
                    return false;
                }
                if(Validate(oForm)){
                    progress_update();
                    document.forms["accesscarddata"].submit();
                }
      }
    </script>
</head>

<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0"
    marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <form name="accesscarddata" id="accesscarddata"
        action="LeaveReportServlet" method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
            background="images/topbkg.gif">
            <tr>
                <td width="50%" valign="top"><img border="0"
                    src="images/logo.gif" width="145" height="66"></td>
                <td width="50%" valign="top">
                    <p align="right">
                        <img border="0" src="images/topright.gif" width="315" height="66">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
            background="img/blackline.gif">
            <tr>
                <td width="100%">
                    <p align="left">
                        <font color="#F0D8B8" face="Arial" size="2"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                slingemp&nbsp;&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp; slingemp&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                |&nbsp;&nbsp; slingemp&nbsp;&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                slingemp&nbsp;&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp; slingemp&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                |&nbsp;&nbsp; slingemp&nbsp;&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp; slingemp</b></font>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p align="center" style="margin-left: 20">
            <font face="Arial" color="#000000" size="4">Attendance Process</font>
        </p>
<div id="statusmessage" style="display:none">
        <table align="center" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="font-size:8pt;padding:2px;border:solid black 1px">
                        <span id="progress1">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
                        <span id="progress2">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
                        <span id="progress3">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
                        <span id="progress4">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
                        <span id="progress5">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
                        <span id="progress6">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
                        <span id="progress7">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
                        <span id="progress8">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
                        <span id="progress9">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
                        <span id="progress10">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
                        <span id="progress11">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
                        <span id="progress12">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
                        <span id="progress13">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
                        <span id="progress14">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
                        <span id="progress15">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
           </tr>
    </table>
</div>
        <p align="left" style="margin-left: 20">
            <font face="Arial" size="2" color="#000000">&nbsp;</font>
        </p>
        <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="25%" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="1%" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="64%" align="left">
                    <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr class="darkrow">
                            <td width="2%" align="left">*</td>
                            <td width="20%" align="left">Start Date</td>
                            <td width="58%" align="left"><input type="text"
                                name="startdate" id="startdate" maxlength="10"
                                onkeyup="formatDate(this)" onblur="isValidDate(this)" /> <img
                                src="images/calpicker.png" name="image" id="startdate"
                                onclick="scwShow(document.forms[0].startdate,event,'');return false;">
                            </td>
                            <td width="20%" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="lightrow">
                            <td width="2%" align="left">*</td>
                            <td width="20%" align="left">End Date</td>
                            <td width="58%" align="left"><input type="text"
                                name="enddate" id="enddate" maxlength="10"
                                onkeyup="formatDate(this)" onblur="isValidDate(this)" /> <img
                                src="images/calpicker.png" name="image" id="startdate"
                                onclick="scwShow(document.forms[0].enddate,event,'');return false;">
                            </td>
                            <td width="20%" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="darkrow">
                            <td width="2%" align="left">*</td>
                            <td width="20%" align="left">Select file</td>
                            <td width="58%" align="left"><input type="file"
                                name="myFile" id="myFile" /></td>
                            <td width="20%" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="lightrow">
                            <td width="2%" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="20%" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="58%" align="left"><input type="button"
                                value="Process" onclick="submitform()" /></td>
                            <td width="20%" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <%
                           if(reportMap.size()>0){ %>
                           <script>
                             progress_stop();
                           </script>
                            <tr class="lightrow">
                                <td width="2%" class="title_sub" align="center">S.No</td>
                                <td width="20%" class="title_sub" align="center">EmployeeID</td>
                                <td width="58%" class="title_sub" align="left">EmployeeName</td>
                                <td width="20%" class="title_sub" align="left">Action</td>
                            </tr>
                            <%
                                        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = reportMap.entrySet().iterator();
                                        while (entries.hasNext()) {
                                            Map.Entry<String, String> entry = entries.next();
                                            if (style % 2 == 0) {
                                                 classname = "darkrow";
                                             } else {
                                                 classname = "lightrow";
                                             }
                                            employeeid = entry.getKey();
                                            employeename = entry.getValue();
                                        %>
                            <tr class='<%=classname %>'>
                                <td width="2%"  align="center"><%=sno %></td>
                                <td width="20%" align="center"><%=employeeid %></td>
                                <td width="58%" align="left"><%=employeename %></td>
                                <td width="20%" align="left"><a href="#" alt='<%=employeeid%>' title='<%=employeeid%>'>sendmail</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <%
                                sno++;
                                style++;

                                        }

                                     }
                                     %>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td width="10%" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <p align="left" style="margin-left: 20">
            <font face="Arial" size="2" color="#000000">&nbsp;</font>
        </p>
        <p align="left" style="margin-left: 20">
            <font face="Arial" color="#000000" size="4">&nbsp;</font>
        </p>
        <p align="left" style="margin-left: 20">
            <font face="Arial" size="2" color="#000000">&nbsp;</font>
        </p>
        <p align="left" style="margin-left: 20">
            <font face="Arial" size="2" color="#000000">&nbsp;</font>
        </p>
        <p align="left" style="margin-left: 20">
            <font face="Arial" size="2" color="#000000">&nbsp;</font>
        </p>
        <p align="center" style="margin-left: 20">
            <font face="Arial" color="#000000" size="1">© COPYRIGHT 2012
                ALL RIGHTS RESERVED SLINGMEDIA.COM</font>
        </p>
        <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
            background="images/botbkg.gif">
            <tr>
                <td width="100%"><img border="0" src="images/botbkg.gif"
                    width="48" height="12"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div
            style="text-align: center; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; font-size: 11px; color: #777;">
            <a style="text-decoration: none; color: #777;"
                href="#">Tutorials</a> | <a
                style="text-decoration: none; color: #777;"
                href="#">Codes</a> | <a
                style="text-decoration: none; color: #777;"
                href="#">Templates</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [HttpSession.removeAttribute(String name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#removeAttribute%28java.lang.String%29).

> Removes the object bound with the specified name from this session. If
>   the session does not have an object bound with the specified name,
>   this method does nothing.

```
if (session.getAttribute("leaveMap") != null) {
    reportMap = (Map<String,String>) session.getAttribute("leaveMap");
    session.removeAttribute("leaveMap");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put data it in `request` scope [request attribute], or override with blank map in Servlet when you make new request

Comment: thanks for the reply, but when i type the url itself the previous values are shown before even making request to a servlet.

Comment: _but when i type the url itself the previous values are shown before even making request to a servlet_ could you please expand this into exact steps you followed

Comment: http://localhost:8080/SlingempLeaveReport/ when i type this url i get the previous values which were there in jsp.

Comment: Yes Tony, Because previously your servlet has kept the data in session scope and you are reading it on jsp and rendering, so it should be there, You need to use request scope or flush that map on each such request

Answer (score 2):

If you are using session then each time after iteratig data you will have to remove that object from session. but if you are using request then you do not need to remove data from request. each time you will get a new request object and new data set as well.